# Why is the question about the intentional blank page has a different name in Google?

Tags: discussion, questions, search, hyperlinks

This question's title doesn't only contain the string *This page is intentionally blank*. Its old title is *This question is intentionally blank*, while the current title is [What's the purpose of “This page is intentionally left blank” we see in books?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/81825/52226).

Yet in Google the there are two results to this question. And the first result doesn't match with any title of the question.

Do you have any explanation for this?

[image: image description]

Comment: I can't say for the top result, but the second result has the date when Google saved the page: Jul 22, 2015, when the title hasn't been edited to current revision.